# NetSuite - Returning an header is not NLAuth scheme error , when I am using OAuth

Tags: oauth, netsuite

I am trying to call a Restlet from a User Event Script which returns Customer information using Token Based Authentication .

But I receive an user error which says header is not NLAuth scheme

I know this means that I have to use the NLAuth scheme , but why is it giving this error?

Here is the authorization header I am using

```
 var headers =  { 'Authorization': 'Oauth realm="XXXXX", oauth_consumer_key="XXXXX" , oauth_token="XXXXX", oauth_nonce="XXX",oauth_timestamp="XXXX", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="XXXXXXXXXX="',
                'content-type': 'application/json'
                };
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to capitalize the "a" in "Oauth"
`Oauth -> OAuth`

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you are using the account ID for the realm and that it is formatted correctly. `12345_SB1` 
The underscore must be used if that applies to your account
The letters must be capitalized.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the latest pattern for realm id in netsuite sandbox environment : ACCOUNTID_SB1

Comment: Correct the underscore is for sandbox accounts. If there is any doubt the account Id found under Setup > Company > Company Information . It has the correct format for now.

Answer (score -4):

Can you try this headers you will get solution

```
var headers = {
    "Authorization": "NLAuth nlauth_account='your account number',nlauth_email='login email' ,nlauth_signature='password'",
    "Content-Type":"application/json"
}
```

Comment: I need OAuth specifically.